# Hiding HTML form elements not using id's

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<h2>Question 1</h2>
<div>
</div>
<div>
  <input type="radio" name="name_radio1" value="value_radio1" onclick=$().hide(); />Audio Question
  <input type="radio" name="name_radio1" value="value_radio2" onclick=$().hide(); />Image Question
  <input type="radio" name="name_radio1" value="value_radio3" onclick=$().hide(); />Standard Question
</div>
<div align="center" style="padding:25px;width: 300px;">
  <input name="question" size="35" class="standardQuestion" type="text" value="" />
  <br>
  <input name="audioFile" class="audioFile" type="file" />
  <br>
  <br>
  <textarea name="message" rows="10" cols="20">
  </textarea>
  <br>
  <input name="imageFile" class="imageFile" type="file" />
  <br>
</div>
<div>

  <h2>Question 2</h2>
  <div>
  </div>
  <div>
    <input type="radio" name="name_radio1" value="value_radio1" onclick=$().hide(); />Audio Question
    <input type="radio" name="name_radio1" value="value_radio2" onclick=$().hide(); />Image Question
    <input type="radio" name="name_radio1" value="value_radio3" onclick=$().hide(); />Standard Question
  </div>
  <div align="center" style="padding:25px;width: 300px;">
    <input name="question" size="35" class="standardQuestion" type="text" value="" />
    <br>
    <input name="audioFile" class="audioFile" type="file" />
    <br>
    <br>
    <textarea name="message" rows="10" cols="20">
    </textarea>
    <br>
    <input name="imageFile" class="imageFile" type="file" />
    <br>
  </div>
  <div>
```

`I am trying to add to an HTML Quiz editor started by someone else that allows me to add from 1 to n questions.  Quiz questions can be based upon an audio recording, an image, or just plain text.  If the question is an audio/image/text based question, I would need to only show the HTML form elements related to an audio/image/text based question.  The questions on the quiz can be changed/updated/deleted by the user of the editor so an audio question could be changed to an image or text based question.  If the question type is changed via a radio button, the appropriate controls for that question type need to be displayed.

For example...

Question 1 
Radio ImageQuestion     Radio AudioQuestion     Radio TextQuestion

textbox 1  (Only show if Radio Button ImageQuestion is checked)

File       (Only show if Radio Button AudioQuestion is checked)

textbox 2  (Only show if Radio Button TextQuestion is checked)

Question 2 (same elements as above)
....

Question N (same elements as above)

While each question will have the same HTML form elements, the data in each question should be independent so when I hide some control for question 1 since the user clicked on a specific radio button there, it should not impact what is diplayed for questions 2 to N.

The key constraint I would like to work with is not use id's since the code that I am working on is over halfway done and has been implemented without id's.  And I could not hardcode the id's since I don't know how many of them will actually be needed.  It would be a significant change to add id's but if that is the only reasonable way or clearly the best way that this can be accomplished, please let me know.  Any advice on the best approach to take would be appreciated.  Right now the code is using jquery/javascript and I would like to stick with that and basic html/css.  I am speculating based upon my research that I may need to use code like .parent().find("a specific class") and the onclick event but I'm not sure if this is the right approach to take and is even feasible.    Thanks.

Comment: Need to provide examples of how you're displaying the questions, showing, hiding, etc. What do you *presently* have, and what is *not working* (what errors do you get, if any, and what other information can you provide about the failure of your attempt(s))?

Comment: You need to put some of the code to support your examples, that way is easier to get a response.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback.  I didn't realize until now how to add code since I am new to posting on this site.   The key point is I'm trying to only display arbitrary elements based upon the radio button selected without using id's.   It really doesn't matter which one's since I'm more concerned about the concept than any particular elements.

Answer (score 0):

Are you trying to do this without javascript?

Comment: I don't mind trying to use javascript and/or jquery.  I am not an expert in either one of them but know enough that if pointed in the right direction, I should be able to solve this.   If pure css/html is easier to solve this that would be fine as well.   With the code I am doing, I am currently using jquery.   I don't want to post the actual code since it is way too long and tied in with grails but this isn't really a grails question since the question seems much more about html/css/jquery/javascript.

Comment: So, just to clarify, when I check 'Standard Question' it's supposed to only show the textarea part and if i check 'Image Question' it's supposed to show the upload, correct?

Comment: Yes, you are correct.   But clicking/checking Standard Question should only affect the question you are working on so if you update question 1, it should be done in a manner that doesn't affect the display of elements on question 2.    And what makes it more difficult for me at least, I would prefer not to use id's.

Comment: Since you do not want to use id's you will have to get the elements either by it's element (ex: div) or by it's classes which will create an array of elements. You will then manipulate the elements by it's index. This can be quite easier to accomplish using JQuery with it's selectors. I can create an example for you when I get home in about thirty minutes if you're willing to wait for it.

Comment: thanks.  An example when you have a little time would be great.  I have been able to get elements by its element like div or I guess p but I guess I don't know how to only update the elements in a certain area so, for example, that certain elements from quiz question 1 are hidden but not quiz question 2 when a radio button for quiz question 1 is selected.